# Laravelのクエリビルダのupdateで元々の値が0に対し0を更新すると0件で返ってくるのはなぜ？

Tags: laravel

Laravel: 6.x
DB: MySQL

```
DB::table('table1')->where($where)->update($sets);
```

updateの戻り値が実際に更新した件数が返りますが、
元々の値が0に対し0を更新すると、
0件で返ってくるのですが、なんででしょうか？

Comment: Laravelの仕様というよりMySQL側の仕様のようですね。https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/mysql-affected-rows.html
_UPDATE ステートメントの場合、デフォルトで影響を受けた行の値は実際に変更された行の数です_　利用しているのはMySQLということでいいですか？

Comment: 返信、ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通り、MySQLを使用しています。CLIENT_FOUND_ROWSフラグを使用すれば、更新というよりWHEREの条件に一致した行数を返すようですが、目的には合致できそうです。ありがとうございました。